# Select all until first occurence of a character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I have data in which the number of characters before a `|` are always different how can I write a `SELECT` statement to get all the characters up to a pipe character?

Sample data:

```
asdf|adkfdll|dd
asdkdkdk|da|d
```

Comment: What should happen with records with no `|` character? It displays the whole string or nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH T(C) AS
(
SELECT 'asdf|adkfdll|dd' UNION ALL
SELECT 'asdkdkdk|da|d' UNION ALL
SELECT ''
)
SELECT  LEFT(C, CHARINDEX('|',C + '|') -1)
FROM T
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `charindex` with `substring`:

```
select  substring(col1, 1, charindex('|',col1))
from    (
        select  'asdf|adkfdll|dd' as col1
        union all
        select  'asdkdkdk|da|d'
        ) as YourData
where   charindex('|',col1) > 0
```