# Select all until first occurence of a character with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select all until the first occurence of a character using an example from "[Select all until first occurence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324318/select-all-until-first-occurence-of-a-character)" but i also need to select other columns such as [docid], [docext], these all come from the tbldoc table....
this works perfect for what i need:

```
select
substring([ErrorMsg], 1, charindex('.',[ErrorMsg]))
from    (
        select  [ErrorMsg]  from tbldoc as col1

        ) as YourData
where   charindex('.',[ErrorMsg]) > 0
and
[ErrorMsg] like '%TrackRevisions%'
```

but when i try to add other columns i get errors,

this is the code i am trying to use:

```
select
tbldoc.[docid], tbldoc.[docext],
substring([ErrorMsg], 1, charindex('.',[ErrorMsg]))
from    (
        select  [ErrorMsg]  from tbldoc as col1

        ) as YourData
where   charindex('.',[ErrorMsg]) > 0
and
[ErrorMsg] like '%TrackRevisions%'
```

this is the error i get:

*Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "tbldoc.docid" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "tbldoc.docext" could not be bound.*

Comment: Why are you using a subquery for start?

Comment: because i'm still learning =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting your error is because your subquery does not contain the fields you want.  However a subquery is not needed here.

```
select
  tbldoc.[docid], 
  tbldoc.[docext],
  substring(tbldoc.[ErrorMsg], 1, charindex('.',tbldoc.[ErrorMsg]))
from   
  tbldoc
where   
  charindex('.',tbldoc.[ErrorMsg]) > 0
  and tbldoc.[ErrorMsg] like '%TrackRevisions%'
```

Comment: wasn't expecting a response so fast, it worked perfect. thank you so much!

Comment: @user2938309 We aim to please. :) Remember to mark your questions as answered and upvote when you have enough rep. Good luck!